# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms. - kafka on pulsar

Tags: apache-kafka, minikube, apache-pulsar

I have installed pulsar using helm chart in minikube. Kafka is installed in local system. When produced a message from kafka cli using kafka-console-producer.bat, getting "Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms." Note that kafka server is not started up, as i am trying to demonstrate kafka on pulsar.

The yaml file used for installing pulsar:
extra:
broker: false
brokerSts: true
proxy: true
wsproxy: false
bastion: false

zookeeper:
replicaCount: 1

bookkeeper:
replicaCount: 1

broker:
component: "broker" # this has to match brokerSts naming
replicaCount: 0

brokerSts:
component: "broker" # this has to match broker naming
replicaCount: 1
functionsWorkerEnabled: true # to overcome the need for functions working
ledger: # the default assumes 2 bookies but this chart only deploys 1
defaultEnsembleSize: 1
defaultAckQuorum: 1
defaultWriteQuorum: 1
service:
ports:
- name: http
port: 8080
- name: pulsar
port: 6650
- name: kafkaplaintext
port: 9092
- name: kafkaschemareg
port: 8001
configData:
PULSAR_PREFIX_protocolHandlerDirectory: "./protocols"
PULSAR_PREFIX_messagingProtocols: "kafka"
PULSAR_PREFIX_brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsEnabled: "false"
PULSAR_PREFIX_saslAllowedMechanisms: PLAIN
PULSAR_PREFIX_brokerEntryMetadataInterceptors: "org.apache.pulsar.common.intercept.AppendIndexMetadataInterceptor"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kopSchemaRegistryEnable: "true"
PULSAR_PREFIX_allowAutoTopicCreationType: "partitioned"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaListeners: "SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaAdvertisedListeners: "SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaTransactionCoordinatorEnabled: "true"
PULSAR_PREFIX_TransactionCoordinatorEnabled: "true"

proxy:
component: "proxy"
replicaCount: 1
service:
ports:
- name: "s4k"
port: 9095
protocol: TCP
- name: "http"
port: 8080
protocol: TCP
- name: "pulsar"
port: 6650
protocol: TCP
configData:
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaListeners: "SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"
# here you have to customize the advertised name if you want to access
# Kafka from outside the kube
# Drop the SASL_PLAINTEXT endpoint if you want to allow only TLS (here and above)
# The Proxy uses the same TLS certificate configured for the Pulsar protocol
#    PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaAdvertisedListeners: "SASL_PLAINTEXT://pulsar-proxy:9092,SASL_SSL://pulsar-proxy:9093"
# if you use port forwarding to localhost then you have to set 'localhost'
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaAdvertisedListeners: "SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"
PULSAR_PREFIX_saslAllowedMechanisms: PLAIN
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaProxySuperUserRole: superuser
PULSAR_PREFIX_kopSchemaRegistryProxyEnableTls: "true"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kopSchemaRegistryEnable: "true"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kopSchemaRegistryProxyPort: "8081"
PULSAR_PREFIX_kafkaTransactionCoordinatorEnabled: "true"
PULSAR_PREFIX_TransactionCoordinatorEnabled: "true"
extensions:
enabled: true
extensions: "kafka"
containerPorts:
- name: kafkaplaintext
containerPort: 9092
- name: kafkaschemareg
containerPort: 8081
servicePorts:
- name: kafkaplaintext
port: 9092
protocol: TCP
targetPort: kafkaplaintext
- name: kafkaschemareg
port: 8081
protocol: TCP
targetPort: kafkaschemareg

image:
proxy:
repository: datastax/lunastreaming-all # so we get the starlight for kafka extension
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
tag: 2.10_2.4
brokerSts:
repository: datastax/lunastreaming-all # so we get the starlight for kafka extension
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
tag: 2.10_2.4
zookeeper:
repository: datastax/lunastreaming
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
tag: 2.10_2.4
bookkeeper:
repository: datastax/lunastreaming
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
tag: 2.10_2.4

My pods:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2XgR.png)

port-forwarded pulsar-broker

kubectl port-forward -n default service/pulsar-broker 9095:9092

Note: in 127.0.0.1 9092, svchost (windoes internal program is running) thus i have port-forwarded to 9095.

after this, opened kafka cli and produced a message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMcNv.png)

Once I enter any value, in port-forward terminal getting handling message like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onpWr.png)

Note: this topic is not existing already. it is a new topic. Acc, to yaml, autotopiccreation is true. So when new topic name is given it has to be created automatically

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC7Hf.png)

Note: Even when i give an already created topic name(created as a pulsar topic), still same error is shown.

Comment: Please don´t  post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a windows application running on that port, once i stopped it, and run kafka on 9092, it is working fine